# How to resample date column loaded from CSV with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I have this data loaded from CSV.

```
        Date                        X           Y           Z
    0   2015-11-30 20:23:05.556     281.764900  -43.895060  8.714666
    1   2015-11-30 20:23:05.757     192.519990  -44.636436  1.720552
    2   2015-11-30 20:23:05.958     149.030600  -45.098050  1.958352
    3   2015-11-30 20:23:06.171     140.707600  -44.622448  1.510729
    4   2015-11-30 20:23:06.366     139.154890  -45.154003  4.783974
    5   2015-11-30 20:23:06.564     138.875140  -44.790306  2.266093
    6   2015-11-30 20:23:06.766     138.357570  -44.048930  4.210457
    7   2015-11-30 20:23:06.967     136.846830  -45.909367  -2.196152
    8   2015-11-30 20:23:07.168     137.322430  -45.126026  0.139882
    9   2015-11-30 20:23:07.369     137.322430  -45.349840  0.587506
    10  2015-11-30 20:23:07.573     132.552460  -48.455223  5.259574
```

The `dtypes` of the columns are these:

```
Date    datetime64[ns]
X              float64
Y              float64
Z              float64
dtype: object
```

I would like to resample `Date`column for example to hundred miliseconds. I tried to use

```
something.unstack().Date.resample('100L').Date.stack()
```

but it wrote just mistake

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex
```

Do you know how to do it?

Comment: what are the dtypes of your columns? also if you read this in using `read_csv` you could've parse the column as a datetime and set it as the index: `df=pd.read_csv(file_path, parse_dates=[0], indexcol=[0])` and then called `resample` on it

Comment: I edited the dtypes. But I have the column as a datetime, so problem is somewhere else I think.

Comment: You can only resample with a datetimeindex so you need to call set_index with date column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
df = df.drop('Date', axis=1)
df = df.resample('resamplestring', how='mean')
```

Comment: I think it's better to modify column `df.Date` and then use `set_index` for `df`: `df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')` and `df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)`